# Magento + simple mail is not working

Tags: php, magento, server, cron

In magento, I have configured a cron job which will run 3 times a day. 
It will send mail to the customers.That is not working from yesterday.
Then, I have tried with a simple php `mail()`, Thats also not working. 
Any clues?

Comment: please check if any extension for mail send already installed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess some problem in your SMTP Server. You have to check with your host.

Before that, Do the following.

I assume, You have HORDE or SQUIRREL-MAIL in your cPanel. 
You just try to send a mail form the clients to your email id.

To open horde, You should go to cPanel -> Mail -> Horde/Squirrelmail.

All d best.